# php multidimensional array from json

Tags: php

The **request** sample of an API is as follows:

```
{
   "channel":"sms",
   "source":"+1xxxxxxxx6",
   "destination":[
      "+1xxxxxxxx"
   ],
   "content":{
      "text":"Hey, Peter. It's Rick.",
      "location":{
         "longitude":"XX.9716",
         "latitude":"XX.5946",
         "label":"California",
         "address":"Test Address"
      },
      "media":{
         "url":"https://media.example.com/file",
         "caption":"your media file"
      }
   },
   "events_url":"https://events.example.com/message"
}
```

Being a newbie, I am having difficulty in setting up the **setContent**, i tried the following and it results in error:

```
    ->setChannel("XXXXXX") 
    ->setSource("+XXXXXXX")  
    ->setDestination(["+1XXXXXXXX"])
    ->setContent(["media"]["url"] => "https://Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg",
"caption" => "My media file test"]) 
    ->setEventsUrl("example.com/events");
```

Error is as follows:
**Error:**
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, `unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'` in

**->setContent(["text" => "This is test message 3"]) works fine..**

I know that this is something basic but being a newbie i can't figure it out. Requesting help.

**UPDATE:**
**Error in documentation**

Comment: The brackets "]" at the end of "My media file test" does not starts anywhere

Comment: The issue was due to non-updated API documentation. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)` error is with `["media"]["url"]`

```
["media"]["url"] => "https://Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg",
"caption" => "My media file test"]
```

you have to initialize an array like

```
[
    "text" =>  "test text",
    "media" =>  [
        "url" => "https://Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg",
        "caption" =>  "My media file test"
    ]
]
```

Comment: Sorry..Error: Invalid value for 'content_type', must be one of 'text', 'location'

Comment: That error means you are missing one of required "text" or "location" in your payload, see my above edit, and post your full payload example if doesn't work

Comment: ok may caption was not in media, try with above edit.

Comment: Caption is in `media` array, not outside.

Comment: @Pamela try to test with above example, if it works with text+media, and you don't need text, than just try with an empty text , like `"text" =>  " "`

Comment: The API documentation is It is one of either text, location or media is allowed

Comment: the error you mentioned in first comment `'content_type', must be one of 'text', 'location'` doesn't write media in it? maybe API has changed and docs were not updated? if you can share publicly API URL it may help others to help you.

Comment: ps, also make sure `'url'` in `media` is valid image URL  and publicly available.

Comment: Yes, i tried using:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Buck_Bunny#/media/File:Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg

Comment: that's not direct link to image, try with `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg`

Comment: The issue was with API documentation. Your answer too was helpful. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create and set following array:

```
[
    'media' =>  [
        'url' => 'https://Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg',
        'caption' =>  'My media file test'
    ]
]
```

Look at the format of sample JSON and make the same levels (dimensions) of your array.

If all fields are mandatory you should send following array:

```
[
    'text' => 'Your text',
    'location' => [
        'longitude' => 'XXX',
        'latitude' => 'XXX',
        'label' => 'your label',
        'address' => 'your address'
    ],
    'media' =>  [
        'url' => 'https://Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg',
        'caption' =>  'My media file test'
    ]
]
```

Comment: Same error:
Exception when calling MessageApi->sendMessage: Invalid value for 'content_type', must be one of 'text', 'location'

Comment: Look at the API documentation and check which fields are mandatory.

Comment: It is one of either text, location or media is allowed